# How to edit engine yard database.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, engineyard

My application staging environment is using `mysql` adapter in `database.yml` file.
but i have included `mysql2` gem in my gemfile, due to which i am having `msql` adapter error.
file is like this?

```
staging:
  adapter:   mysql
  database:  myapp
  username:  xyz
  password:  IiVTKgcJCt
  host:      ec2-50-16-127-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  reconnect: true
```

how can i change adapter to `mysql2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal circumstances your database.yml will be set to use the correct adapter automatically by Engine Yard. If this is not occurring you may have a configuration issue that is causing this issue. If this is still a concern for you I recommend opening a ticket with our support team so we can assist you further. https://support.cloud.engineyard.com

Thank you,

Tyler

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation and ended up uploading a custom cookbook to write out the database.yml file.  I used this example I found on the googles:

https://gist.github.com/1989695